# Is it possible to use ECMAScript 2018 in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I wrote a code in a django template that works very well in all other browsers but Internet Explorer, is it possible to make it work with the current version of javascript i'm using with other browsers?

Comment: Yes it’s possible, use Babel.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to use [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill).